# adding separate custom header for inner pages of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, themes

I am newer to wordpress.i have added a header image for the home page using custom header from Appearance->Header.I have to add different image to the inner pages.how can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use featured image

http://robcubbon.com/featured-images-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-headers/